# Adding widevine to my QT project doesn't work

Tags: qt, widevine

I downloaded the `widevinecdm.dll` file from Chrome, then in my .pro file in QT i enabled propietary codecs as said  [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtwebengine-features.html#audio-and-video-codecs) i added also the path to the dll like this `QTWEBENGINE_CHROMIUM_FLAGS=--widevine-path="C:\Users\FRANC\OneDrive\Desktop\Programacion\Proyectos\C++\widevinecdm.dll"` but i still can't play netflix or any streaming service. any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was solved after building QtWebEngine with proprietary codecs enabled.